# Python: New Mac Update Changes Things

Tags: python, macos, cocoa, loops, time

I just updated my mac's osx.
Before the update, a program like this:

```
from Cocoa import NSSpeechSynthesizer
import time

sp = NSSpeechSynthesizer.alloc().initWithVoice_(None)

def say(x):
    sp.startSpeakingString_(x)
    while sp.isSpeaking():
        time.sleep(0.1)
while True:
    say("chocolate")
    say("vanilla")
```

Would have had my computer say `chocolate vanilla chocolate vanilla` over and over forever.

But now after the update it seems that the (which is supposed to wait until its done speaking to continue the next thing)

```
while sp.isSpeaking():
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

is forgotten about when it is at the end of a loop, and the computer simply repeats `vanilla` over and over.

(I know I could do `say("chocolate, vanilla")` but this isn't about that. This is about the loop being forgotten when it is in a loop)

Comment: First, what version of OS X did you update from, and what version did you update to? Also, are you using Apple's pre-installed Python and PyObjC?

Comment: Second, the indentation of the code you posted here is clearly wrong, because it will raise an `IndentationError` for the first call to `say`. And if the indentation in your _actual_ code, which we can't see, is wrong, that could easily cause the problems you're seeing. (For example, if the `while` is dedented to the margin, it will only wait before starting the main loop, instead of each time within `say`.)

Comment: By the way, if your real program is a normal Cocoa app with an `NSRunLoop`, you may want to consider setting a delegate for `speechSynthesizer_didFinishSpeaking_` instead of polling the `speaking` property like this.

Comment: @abarnert Yeah sorry, I fixed the indentation, I had just put it wrong on here. I am using pre-installed python 2.7.6 to run my scripts, but I am using IDLE from a python 2.7.6 that I installed to type it. As for pyobjc, I do believe I am using that, I remember installing something of the sort along with appkit in order to us NSSpeechSynthesizer. I updated to Yosemite from Mavericks.

Comment: OK, your answers are confusing. If you installed another Python 2.7.6 to get its IDLE, then it's that _other_ Python 2.7.6 that's being used when you run from within IDLE, and it _may_ be that other one when you run from the command line, depending on how you run scripts and what your `$PATH` looks like. Can you `import sys` and `print sys.executable` at the top of your script? Meanwhile, PyObjC is the package that includes `Cocoa` and `AppKit`; Apple pre-installs it with their Python, but most other Python installations don't include it. Can you `import objc` and `print objc.__version__`?

Comment: @abarnert So print objc.__version__ returns 2.5.1 (in both pythons).

Comment: @abarnert And print sys.executable returns `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python` in terminal, and it returns `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python` in the IDLE Shell.

Comment: OK, you have at least three copies of Python 2.7. Besides the Apple one, which you're not actually using, you have the one in `/opt/local`, which probably came from MacPorts, and the one in `/usr/local/Cellar`, which definitely came from Homebrew. You shouldn't be mixing MacPorts and Homebrew, period. And you shouldn't have three different Python 2.7 installations and switch between them haphazardly. What happens if you use Apple's Python for this script, by running `/usr/bin/python2.7 myscript.py`?

Comment: For that matter, do you get the same behavior (`isSpeaking` always returning false) on both your command-line Python and your IDLE Python?

Comment: Finally: I think PyObjC 3.0 has been out for a while now, and contains a variety of fixes for OS X 10.10 and even 10.9 that will probably never get backported to a 2.5.2, so however you installed it, you may want to consider upgrading.